# What is meant by Guru?

Tags: gurus

I often hear this word and I think I have some doubts because in Hinduism Jupiter is called Guru.
So maybe I could be misunderstanding.
What do lamas mean when they say guru?
Could Shree Ganesha be my Guru?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guru in Sanskrit or Garu in Pali, means teacher.

But in the context of your question, [Guru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guru#In_Buddhism) is a spiritual teacher who confers blessings on his disciple, and whose disciple has devotion towards the spiritual teacher. The disciple trusts that the spiritual teacher will lead him to liberation. The disciple treats the Guru as a Buddha or a deity. The Guru has a direct spiritual link or spiritual connection with the disciple. The Guru is also called the Vajra Guru. The Guru may perform ritual empowerment or initiation upon the disciple. This is found only in Tibetan Buddhism/ Vajrayana.

[Ganesha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ganesha_in_world_religions#Tibetan_Buddhism) as a deity and Guru, is also found only in Tibetan Buddhism/ Vajrayana, not as the Hindu God, but rather as an emanation of [Avalokiteshvara](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Avalokite%C5%9Bvara).

In Theravada Buddhism, the only true spiritual teacher is the Buddha, to whom all take refuge in. Refuge in the Dhamma (teachings of the Buddha) and the collective Sangha is also taken, but not refuge in any individual teacher. The ordinary teacher, say venerables like Ajahn Brahm or Ajahn Yuttadhammo, do not have spiritual or supernatural links to their students. What the students have, is admirable friendship (*kalyanamittata*) with their ordinary teacher, based on [SN 45.2](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn45/sn45.002.than.html) and [AN 8.54](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an08/an08.054.than.html). The student does not have devotion towards their ordinary teacher but they may have trust in him. The ordinary teacher does not confer supernatural blessings upon the student. The student does not value the words of the ordinary teacher as being equal to the words of the Buddha.

Comment: So I can consider Ganesh as my Guru?!

Comment: @CaneRandagio It's best to consult Tibetan Buddhism teachers.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no, not really, but if you want more confirmation you should find a local respected teacher from a Tibetan, Nepalese, or Mongolian lineage and consult with them. Most likely your best bet would be to find a living guru.

Long answer:
I'm mostly familiar with Chan (Mahayana) and Theravada. In the Theravada the idea of a guru is almost nonexistent, and in Mahayana (including Chan/Zen), a specific master is important but not held at the same level that a guru is in Tibetan Buddhism/Vajrayana. Gurus are essential in the Vajrayana because some of the teachings are *esoteric*, not to be carelessly revealed to anyone because they require guidance and preparation. Usually "guru" in Buddhism refers to your immediate teacher, but can also refer to anyone in their direct lineage (your teacher's teacher, their teacher, etc., back to Padmasambhava, Virupa, Tsongkhapa, etc., and further back to the historical Buddha, Vairocana, or some other Buddha. In casual usage, this is less common and guru usually means your primary teacher, the one you're loyal to and show devotion towards in this lifetime, in person.

Could Ganesha be your guru? Well, Buddhists don't exactly believe in Ganesha in the same way that Hindus do. Vajrayana has Vinayaka and sometimes Heramba, who is essentially Ganesha, who is a deva (or demon, in at least one form), but deity yoga (in Vajrayana) is different from Guru yoga, and outside of Vajrayana as far as I know it doesn't exist at all (though we do revere other Buddhas and Bodhisattvas, which are a similar concept but not exactly the same).

Comment: Guru is not exactly non existent in theravada, its just simply not seen in the same way. A guru is essentially a teacher and the Buddha advised to seek virtuous friends, with of course a teacher being just that. It is not seen as such that a teacher is superior and the student lesser. Honorific titles for X amount of rain seasons/years ordained is the only veneration in theravada. The Guru idea is hindu, that is why it has crept into vajrayana/tibetan buddhism as some sort of necessity. The actual fact is the Buddha is the guru, his teachings is the point which one can read themselves.

Answer (score 1):

Guru is a word (Hindi and Sanskrit) that literally means teacher. Connotatively it comes to mean master, spiritual guide, etc. Rinpoche is Tibetan for Guru (amongst one meanings). All gods and goddesses can be guru [M.] (gurudain [F.]). Jupiter is also considered as a Guru. Ganesh is also a guru.

Guru-shishya (teacher-disciple) relation is very specific to Ancient Indian subcontinent, where oral transmission has been a form of teaching (at times the only). Within Tibetan Buddhism, this teacher-student relation is very important as the answer by @Zac Anger emphasizes.

In contemporary India, people still call their spiritual teachers as guru.

Answer (score 1):

Guru this word is very pregnant! it carries multiple meanings depending on context used.

You see how I used *guru* to address you in sentence ' *Guru this word is very pregnant!* ', saying guru (just as we use 'guys' in english) is common way of addressing a person in friendly way in *hindi* slang.

*Guru* as a noun the word means the imparter of dnyana (knowledge).As an adjective, it means 'heavy,' or 'weighty,' eg; gravity is called *gurutvakarshan* in most Indian languages.The word has its roots in the Sanskrit gri (to invoke, or to praise).

> गुशब्दस्त्वन्धकारः स्यात्‌ रुशब्दस्तन्निरोधकः ।
> अन्धकारनिरोधित्वात्‌ गुरुरित्यभिधीयते ॥ १६॥
> The syllable gu means darkness, the syllable ru, he who dispels them,
> Because of the power to dispel darkness, the guru is thus named.
> — Advayataraka Upanishad, Verse 16

In India even the elementary school teacher is referred as Guru! The conman figures (who are mostly found criminals hiding behind the cult) are also called Guru. In a way *Guru* is used by atheists and revolutionary thinkers in *negative* way to reffer a person exploiting others in name of spirituality or knowledge.

Planet Jupiter is called guru in Hindu mythology because he was Teacher of Gods, more or less like Chiron in Greek mythology; that's why the Jupiter is also called guru.

Ganesha is not a Guru, he is diety. He is often used as symbol for vidya along with godess Saraswati.They are like qualities personified. For a simile, Ganesha is fragrance while a Guru is flower. So you can't accept Ganesha as Guru.

> You know, if we understand one question rightly, all questions are answered. But we don't know how to ask the right question. To ask the right question demands a great deal of intelligence and sensitivity. Here is a question, a fundamental question: is life a torture? It is, as it is; and man has lived in this torture centuries upon centuries, from ancient history to the present day, in agony, in despair, in sorrow; and he doesn't find a way out of it. Therefore he invents gods, churches, all the rituals, and all that nonsense, or he escapes in different ways. What we are trying to do, during all these discussions and talks here, is to see if we cannot radically bring about a transformation of the mind, not accept things as they are, nor revolt against them. Revolt doesn't answer a thing. You must understand it, go into it, examine it, give your heart and your mind, with everything that you have, to find out a way of living differently. That depends on you, and not on someone else, because in this there is no teacher, no pupil; there is no leader; there is no guru; there is no Master, no Saviour. You yourself are the teacher and the pupil; you are the Master; you are the guru; you are the leader; you are everything. And to understand is to transform what is.
> I think that will be enough, won't it?
> J. Krishnamurti